# Excel Worksheet Vsto Object Null Reference Exeption

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am planning to automate an Excel workbook. For this I need buttons in individual cells. I have read that I can realize this with this code:

```
Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range["A2"];
Tools.Controls.Button button = new Tools.Controls.Button();
worksheetVsto.Controls.AddControl(button,range, "Drück mich");
```

I am planning to automate an Excel workbook. For this I need buttons in individual cells. I have read that I can realize this with this code:

```
Tools.Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveSheet);
```

Unfortunately, I get a null reference exception on this line every time. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which property or method throws an exception in the code. A single line of code contains too many property or method calls. Anyway, you can use the following code to add a control:

```
var workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) sheet;
var vstoSheet = workSheet.GetVstoObject();
var button = vstoSheet.Controls.AddButton(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test");
button.Text = "Dynamic Button!";
```

See [Walkthrough: Add controls to a worksheet at run time in VSTO add-in project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-adding-controls-to-a-worksheet-at-run-time-in-vsto-add-in-project?view=vs-2022) for more information.